# Not able to upload file with more than 1MB size in WildFly 10?

Tags: java, http, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I know it may look simple, but I am supposed to upload an XML file which is **`12 MB`**. It doesn't upload onto the server (accessing through domain name www.xyz.com)! but when I login to remote server and access using localhost I am able to upload a file which is more than 1MB, whereas from DNS I am able to upload XML which is less than 1MB.

Here is what I tried. I increased the size in `standalone.xml` but doesn't work.

```
 <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="50485760"/>
```

I am using prime faces.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set `max-header-size` to the same value required for `max-post-size`. This depends on whether your clients request is a multipart (including a streamed file) or a giant 'form field'.